# React Hooks not updating

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm a student so sorry for the messy code. The problem is the `startTime` hook. I initialize it as 0 and then set it to `Date.now()` in the `startTimer` function. However it doesn't get updated until the second time I press it. Why is this?

I commented where the problem is.
Also sorry if something is wrong, this is my first post.

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
//import { render } from '@testing-library/react';

function Stopwatch() {

  const [milliSecondsHook, setMilliSecondsHook] = useState(0);
  const [secondsHook, setSecondsHook] = useState(0);
  const [minutesHook, setMinutesHook] = useState(0);
  const [hoursHook, setHoursHook] = useState(0);
  const [running, setRunning] = useState(2);
  const [id, setId] = useState(0);
  const [split, setSplit] = useState(0);
  const [startTime, setStartTime] = useState(0);

  function toggleRunning() {
    running ? setRunning(0) : setRunning(1);
    if(running == 1) {
      setRunning(0);
    } else if(running == 0) {
      setRunning(1);
    } else {
      setRunning(1);
    }
  }

  function pauseTimer(id) {
    startTimer();
  }

  const milliSeconds = (diff) => diff % 1000 / 10 //milliseconds
  const seconds = (diff) => (diff / 1000) % 60; //seconds
  const minutes =(diff) => (diff / 1000 / 60) % 60; //minutes
  const hours = (diff) => diff / 1000 / 60 / 60; //hours

  function timer(startTime) {
    var intervalId = setInterval(function() {

      let currentTime = Date.now();
      let diff = currentTime - startTime;
      setMilliSecondsHook(Math.trunc(milliSeconds(diff)));
      setSecondsHook(Math.trunc(seconds(diff)));
      setMinutesHook(Math.trunc(minutes(diff)));
      setHoursHook(Math.trunc(hours(diff)));

    }, 50);
    return intervalId;
  }

  function startTimer() {
    console.log(running);
    if(running == 2) {
      setStartTime(Date.now()); //this is the problem, it doesnt update the render.
    }

    toggleRunning();

    if(running == 0 || running == 2) {
      clearInterval(id);
      setId(timer(startTime));
    } else if (running == 1) {
      clearInterval(id);
    }
  }

  function splitTime() {
    //copy hooks
  }


if(running == 0) {
  return (
    <div>
      <div>{milliSecondsHook}:{secondsHook}:{minutesHook}:{hoursHook}</div>
      <input type="submit" value="start" onClick={startTimer}></input>
      <input type="submit" value="split" onClick={splitTime}></input>
    </div>
  )
}
if(running == 2) {
  return (
    <div>
      <div>{milliSecondsHook}:{secondsHook}:{minutesHook}:{hoursHook}</div>
      <input type="submit" value="start" onClick={startTimer}></input>
      <input type="submit" value="split" onClick={splitTime}></input>
    </div>
  )
}
else if(running == 1) {
  return (
    <div>
      <div>{milliSecondsHook}:{secondsHook}:{minutesHook}:{hoursHook}</div>
      <input type="submit" value="pause" onClick={pauseTimer}></input>
      <input type="submit" value="split" onClick={splitTime}></input>
    </div>
  )
} else {
  return (
    <div>
      <div>{milliSecondsHook}:{secondsHook}:{minutesHook}:{hoursHook} wrong</div>
      <input type="submit" value="start" onClick={startTimer}></input>
      <input type="submit" value="split" onClick={splitTime}></input>
    </div>
  )
}

}

export default Stopwatch;
```

Comment: what is the purpose of running? why there are all the if statements that return a different view?

Comment: When you call `setRunning(..)`, the value of `running` isn't changed immediately (because setting state is async). So your `toggleRunning` function won't work like you expect it to. And if all those views are about split times, you need to completely change your approach anyway.

Comment: The code you posted seems to be working: https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-leavitt-rny6s